# Migration of Wordpress sites to a local WAMPserver, now the pages cannot be found

Tags: wordpress, wamp, wampserver

Recently at our agency we needed to do a serious overhaul of our servers, so I've had to migrate the sites onto a local host machine so that I could work on them in the meantime. I used WAMPserver to host the sites, and the sites are powered by Wordpress. When the move was complete, I checked the sites on my local host to see how they looked. The front pages looked perfectly fine, but whenever I tried to navigate to the inner pages, I was met with nothing but 404s. My supervisor believes it might be connection issue, but I wanted to check here first to see if anyone else had similar problems.

**OS:** Windows 7
**WAMPserver version:** 2.2

**Steps already taken**

- I made sure that the local databases were named exactly as they were on the original server, and I double-checked with the wp-config file.
- I made sure to obtain the SQL files for the databases and imported
  them in phpmyadmin.
- I went into the SQL files and changed all of the links (changed all instances of http://www.sitename.com to http://localhost/sitename)
- I logged into the Wordpress admin dashboard to check if all of the content was actually there. Everything was intact, but even clicking on "view post/page" on each individual post/page resulted in a 404.
- I tried returning the permalink options to default and then changing them back, but that didn't work.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide any more information as I am no longer in the office. I hope that I can receive some help by the time I go back in tomorrow morning.

Comment: There's a http://wordpress.stackexchange.com site which might be a better fit for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like an issue with mod_rewrite. Try adding `AllowOverride All` to your virtual host.

If that doesn't work then also check your httpd.conf for the following line

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Make sure it's not commented out.

Comment: WAMPserver doesn't activate it by default (yeah great decision</sarcasm>). It's there: `(left click on icon) / Apache / Apache modules / rewrite_module`

Comment: Thank you very much. I did exactly what you said and it worked. I also found the answer at http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_Permalink_Problems

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations That makes sense because apache doesn't enable it by default either.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info, it seems my sysadmin always activate it and I took that for granted :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I migrated from `example.com` to `localhost/example` when this error started showing up. `mod_rewrite` was on. What I had to do was edit `.htaccess` and change the last line in the block `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` (line 8 for me) from this

`RewriteRule . /index.php [L]`

to this

`RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]`